# Find domain details if whois is empty

Tags: domain, whois

Is it possible to find out domain data if whois(from many different whois services) are empty.

And how can i protect my own domains from whois?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to _" protect"_ from whois? Also see: https://whois.icann.org/en/basics-whois

Comment: If some of the whois data is redacted for privacy, then no. Unless you're a three letter agency. As for protecting your own data, it depends on a) your domain registrar and b) the TLD. Some TLDs (and/or registrars) don't support domain privacy, so it'll be a question for your registrar.